# Checkbox checked CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

Hi everyone i am trying to make a checkbox using CSS.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/YPvgWq)** from *codepen.io*

In this demo you can see there is a tree checkbox button *(YES,NO,MAYBE)*

My question is this: Let's say the user first clicked the button YES.The user then gave up and click on the NO button. I want to make it when user clicked NO button then Yes button automatically unchecked. How can i do that anyone can help me ?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno"/>Yes
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno"/>no
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno"/>maybe
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}
.yesno {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  outline: 0;
  background: #9da6b0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yesno:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 11px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.yesno:checked {
  background: #529ecc;
}
.yesno:checked:after {
  left: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes. They will automatically handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply make those elements radio buttons with the same name attribute:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYRPxZ)

In doing so, the elements are mutually exclusive, and only one can be selected at once.

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="yes-no" class="yesno"/>Yes
  <input type="radio" name="yes-no" class="yesno"/>no
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno"/>maybe
</div>
```

Comment: @innovation Yep. That essentially attaches the radio elements together.

Comment: I understood thank you. I have 8 minutes for accepted your answer. Thanks again for this clean answer.

Comment: Can you tell me please. If user clicked second time checked radio button then that clicked radio button was going to be unchecked ?

Comment: No, if you need the ability to uncheck again, you will be better going back to check-boxes

Answer (score 0):

They should definitely be radio buttons, but here's the JavaScript.

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno" id="yesCheckbox"/>Yes
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno" id="noCheckbox"/>no
  <input type="checkbox" class="yesno" id="maybeCheckbox"/>maybe
</div>

$('#yesCheckbox').click(function() {
  if($(this.prop('checked')))
  {
    $('#noCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```